# Tool which dumps the Python Stacktrace of all running Interpreters

Tags: python, debugging

If one of our linux system is overloaded, then I would like to take a snapshot of what is going on.

99% of our code is Python, that's why I would like to get a stacktrace of all running python interpreters.

I have no clue how to get the stacktrace of python processes.

This question is only about how to get the stacktrace. The condition which checks if I want it to happen is a different question (which is already solved).

I know that it is possible to get the stacktrace by using a signal handler (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2569696/633961)), but I would like to avoid this. The python source code should not get modified to solve this.

Comment: Just curious - how would stack traces help you determine the cause of system overload?

Comment: @Mawg you want to know why stacktraces help me? Because I can see what is going on. If I just know "some python processes are running at 100% CPU" I do not know much. But if I can see the stacktraces, then I can see what the python processes are actually doing.

Comment: Thanks (+1) I was wondering how, without looking in detail at ***lots*** of stack dumps, you would know which one was causing the 100% CPU. Can't you give them all unique process name, then run `top` or look at the Windows `taskmgr`, to see which process is hogging CPU? And can't you limit their CPU somehow? In short, I am wondering of this is really the best question for you to ask :-)

Comment: @Mawg if this is not the best question, which one would be better?

Comment: To me, it sounds like a "which process is eating my CPU" question? Wouldn't `top` help? Can't you give them all unique process names, have another process which is a watchdog and when CPU > 90% it snapshots the offender? Or, can't you use the O/S's parameters to `create process/thread`, to limit CPU usage, as you can stack size? Maybe adjust priority? You might get better help on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mawg this question is not about linux processes. It is about python processes. I want to know what's the interpreter is doing. I can't see this with the command line tools `top` or `ps`.

Comment: I think I am probably missing the point; sorry. Seems to me that you could use `top` to quickly find out ***which*** Python script causes the problems, and then investigate it. Perhaps you could profile it, and see which areas are causing most problems, then examine them (looks at loops & the other usual suspects).  I am just not sure that looking at the stack will pinpoint the problem. But, I see that you found a solution. It is good to accept your own answer, as this will help others in furture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool [pyrasite](https://github.com/lmacken/pyrasite):

> Tools for injecting arbitrary code into running Python processes.

This way you can get a stacktrace of running python processes.

No need to modify the python source and no need to work with signal handlers :-)

Answer (score 0):

The tool [python-hunter](https://python-hunter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) could be used to extract the stacktraces

> Hunter is a flexible code tracing toolkit, not for measuring coverage, but for debugging, logging, inspection and other nefarious purposes. It has a Python API, terminal activation (see Environment variable activation). and supports tracing other processes

Answer (score 0):

The too [pyflame](https://github.com/uber/pyflame#is-there-a-way-to-just-dump-stack-traces) can be used to dump stacktraces of running interpreters:

> Is There A Way To Just Dump Stack Traces?
>
> Yes, use the -d option.

Comment: It looks like pyflame is no longer. maintained, but https://github.com/benfred/py-spy is a potential alternative.